# How I can run contour_moments.cpp OpenCV example?

Tags: ros, opencv, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don’t know how to run the file contour_moments.cpp that’s able in this github link: https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/blob/indigo/opencv_apps/src/node/contour_moments.cpp

I’m working with Indigo and I have installed OpenCV3 following this ROS.org link:
http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv

when i run the command `rosrun opencv_apps contour_moments`
it only appear a warning and nothing else:

```
[ WARN] [1450293289.992148166]: Topic 'image' has not been remapped! Typical command-line usage:
    $ rosrun image_rotate image_rotate image:=<image topic> [transport]
```

which topic should I use?? (I'm using a kinect, and it is working fine)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222442/how-i-can-run-contour_moments.cpp-opencv-example?/) by [G212](https://answers.ros.org/users/25216/g212/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-12-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clynamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8871/clynamen/) on 2015-12-13**:
paste the errors here then

**Comment by [clynamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8871/clynamen/) on 2015-12-13**:
The required target_link_libraries are listed in the CMakeLists.txt file in the repository.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-12-14**:
It might be easier to start with the entire vision_opencv package and progressively remove things from it until it is only building `contour_moments`.  Don't use OpenCV 3 unless you really need it instead of 2.4, building with it has some issues.

**Comment by [G212](https://answers.ros.org/users/25216/g212/) on 2015-12-14**:
Ok, so I have to uninstall OpenCV3 before installing Opencv2? .. If so, how do I do that?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-12-14**:
OpenCV 2 is probably already installed in parallel if you have cv_bridge installed.  If you have OpenCV 3 from debian/ubuntu packages `sudo apt-get remove ros-indigo-opencv3`

**Comment by [G212](https://answers.ros.org/users/25216/g212/) on 2015-12-16**:
ok, now when i run the command `rosrun opencv_apps contour_moments` it only appear a warning and nothing else ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These nodes do not publish any message unless someone is reading that. so try

```
roslaunch opencv_apps contour_moments.launch image:=image_raw
```

and

```
 rostopic echo /contour_moments/moment
```

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2017-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0